# add networkx layout to holoview graph

Tags: pandas, dataframe, layout, networkx, holoviews

I applied facebook network sample from  [this documentation](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/network_graph.html) on my work, to get this code:

```
    edges_df = pd.read_csv('rel.csv', delimiter= ";")
    nodes_df = pd.read_csv('monfichier.csv', delimiter= ";")

    padding = dict(x=(-1.1, 1.1), y=(-1.1, 1.1))

    fb_nodes = hv.Dataset(nodes_df, 'index')
    fb_graph = hv.Graph((edges_df, fb_nodes)).redim.range(**padding)

    colors = ['#000000'] + hv.Cycle('Category20').values

    fb_graph.opts(color_index='age', show_frame=False,
                  xaxis=True, yaxis=True, node_size=10, edge_line_width=1, cmap=colors)

    renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')

    plot = renderer.get_plot(fb_graph).state
    show(plot)
```

It works fine. But the resulted network was a graph  without a specific layout (as shown in attached figure). I want to specify the network layout as in networkx. How to do that ?
[image: attached figure]

I found, this instruction:

```
hv.Graph.from_networkx(G, nx.layout.spring_layout).opts(tools=['hover'])
```

But I did not find how to use it with my code, since my G is already an holoview and not a networkx graph.
Do you have any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function called `layout_nodes` in HoloViews which can apply networkx (and other) layouts to an existing graph:

```
N = 8
node_indices = np.arange(N)
source = np.zeros(N)
target = node_indices

padding = dict(x=(-1.2, 1.2), y=(-1.2, 1.2))

simple_graph = hv.Graph(((source, target),)).redim.range(**padding)
hv.element.graphs.layout_nodes(simple_graph, layout=nx.spring_layout)
```

Comment: I tried this sample,and some others found on internet with this instruction  "hv.element.graphs.layout_nodes", but the layout is the same whatever is the layout used. Did I miss something ?

Comment: You would have to post what exactly you tried. Do note that the function returns a new object and does not modify the existing one.

Comment: edges_df = pd.read_csv('rel.csv')
        nodes_df = pd.read_csv('monfichier.csv')

        padding = dict(x=(-1.1, 1.1), y=(-1.1, 1.1))

        fb_nodes = hv.Dataset(nodes_df, 'index')
        fb_graph = hv.Graph((edges_df, fb_nodes)).redim.range(**padding)
        hv.element.graphs.layout_nodes(fb_graph, layout=nx.kamada_kawai_layout)
            
        renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
        plot = renderer.get_plot(fb_graph).state
        show(plot)

Comment: As I said, you need to assign the object returned by the layout_nodes function back to a variable.

Comment: Thanks  philippjfr for your help. It works as you said.